# Do particles produce gravitational waves?

Tags: general-relativity, particle-physics, gravity, gravitational-waves, estimation

We have obviously detected gravitational waves at very large scales, but what about small scales? I accept the answer that they would be indetectable, however I would think it would, considering the incredible speed of a photon, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Studying General Relativity (GR) one learns that what we call gravity is space time distortions due to the energy and momentum vector carried by massive objects. It is describe by specific tensors connecting [energy momentum with space time curvature.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity#Einstein's_equations). This is a classical physics system. [It can be mathematically  shown within GR](https://www.tat.physik.uni-tuebingen.de/~kokkotas/Teaching/NS.BH.GW_files/GW_Physics.pdf) that time varying gravitational fields generate gravitational waves , similar to time varying electric and magnetic fields generate electromagnetic waves but the mass distributions should be asymmetric:

> The factor ε is a measure of the asymmetry of
>   the source and implies that only a time varying quadrupole moment will emit gravitational waves.

This is the classical level. BUT particles are governed by quantum mechanics . At the moment there is no definite quantized gravity model. There are hypothesis on the same lines as the other three forces, strong,weak ,electromagnetic, that gravitational waves are composed of gravitons, but there is as yet no experimental proof of the graviton's existence.

For a particle, which has energy and momentum, an off mass shell gravitational interaction can be hypothesized in cosmological models. [Elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) though, like the electron or the photon are point particles, so they are symmetric, and no matter what their energy, they will not emit gravitational waves.

Maybe one could compute gravitational  waves from asymmetric nanoparticles, but they would be too weak to be detected. After all it is with the sun masses involved in black hole merging that the classical gravitational waves have been seen.

Please note that it is not speed that is involved in the gravitational equations, but the energy momentum tensor, and the photon has energy according to the frequency of the light it is part of ¨$E=hν$.

Comment: I don’t understand your point about symmetric particles. As soon as a mass is accelerated it produces gravitational waves even if it is symmetric or point like, doesn‘t it?

Comment: @HartmutBraun In general acceleration brings asymmetry in so accelerated mass point would indeed produce gravitational waves. The symmetrical acceleration would be for example radially pulsating star (so that the expansion of the star will not break symmetry of mass distribution), which will not produce gravitational waves.

Comment: A fun example is "gravitational atoms": place two particles in orbit around each other. They would indeed radiate away energy just like two stars do since the system has a quadrupole moment. But *very* slowly (and such systems tend to be absurdly big: an electron-neutrino "atom" is around $10^{21}$ pc wide).

Comment: @AndersSandberg  if there is quantization of gravity there will be bound states of that size. It is the argument of why atoms are stable and not radiate.em waves

Comment: @Umaxo you need a quadrupole moment, does acceleration create quadrupole moments? It is accelerating ( time varying) quadrupole moments of the mass thatgenerate gravitational waves.( for electromagnetic  it needs dipole only. Dipole can be geometrically seen in an accelerated charge. But how quadrupole unless the mass is asymmetric?

Comment: @annav - A quantized gravitational atom would presumably eventually decay to the 1s state.

Comment: When you say _"...but the mass distributions should be asymmetric"_ did you mean that a departure from **spherical symmetry** of the source is required for generating GWs, at least classically? @annav

Comment: Yes, a symmetric source, when accelerating  can only give up to dipole moments. Gravitational radiation needs quadrupole, so there should be some asymmetry that would allow the expansion to higher than dipole moments.

Comment: Interesting! It means that a uniform spherical mass distribution, contracting and expanding periodically but retaining spherical symmetry is incapable of sending ripples through spacetime. @annav